# Semantic MediaWiki - Properties are displaying in duplicate

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

I have a template that defines a subobject in which I define properties, including `Summary Pagename={{FULLPAGENAME}}`, among others. When I then query

```
[[Summary Pagename::(page I'm looking for)]]
```

it shows me all the subobjects I expect to see, however, depending on the page I query, I sometimes get every subobject in duplicate.

In particular, if the pagename is of the form `..../Scoreboards` it displays in duplicate; however, usually the pagename will be of the form `..../Scoreboards/[something else]` and then everything works as intended.

It might be relevant that in some cases, `..../Scoreboards` will have subpages, but in others it doesn't, but regardless of whether it has subpages or not this duplication still happens.

[Here's a direct link to a page showing this problem.](http://lol.esportspedia.com/w/index.php?title=Special%3AAsk&q=[[Summary%20Pagename%3A%3ARiot%20League%20Championship%20Series%2FNorth%20America%2F2014%20Season%2FSummer%20Promotion%2FScoreboards]]%20[[Summary%20MatchNo%3A%3A001]]%20[[SP%20GameNo%3A%3A001]]&po=&eq=yes&p[format]=broadtable&sort_num=&order_num=ASC&p[limit]=500&p[offset]=&p[link]=all&p[sort]=&p[headers]=show&p[mainlabel]=&p[intro]=&p[outro]=&p[searchlabel]=...%20further%20results&p[default]=&p[class]=sortable%20wikitable%20smwtable&eq=yes) It seems pretty weird to me, but anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: duplicate properties can happen if your properties are both stored on a page and on on a subobject level. I'v seen this before and so fare have worked around it. It might be a bug and therefore it would be good to show an example on e.g. http://www.semantic-mediawiki.org

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the subobject seems to reference back the page (so I think that's why changing the pagename seems to fix the issue), as if it's querying twice the same thing (I know, total weirdness I don't fully understand it either).

So browsing the properties there are no duplicates, so I changed the query using an [inverse property](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Inverse_properties) instead to retrieve what you need. This would give you the results without duplicates:

```
[[-Has subobject::(page I'm looking for)]] 
[[Summary MatchNo::001]] 
[[SP GameNo::001]]
```

[search example](http://lol.esportspedia.com/w/index.php?title=Special%3AAsk&q=%5B%5B-Has%20subobject%3A%3ARiot%20League%20Championship%20Series%2FNorth%20America%2F2014%20Season%2FSummer%20Promotion%2FScoreboards%5D%5D%20%5B%5BSummary%20MatchNo%3A%3A001%5D%5D%20%5B%5BSP%20GameNo%3A%3A001%5D%5D&po=&eq=yes&p%5Bformat%5D=broadtable&sort_num=&order_num=ASC&p%5Blimit%5D=500&p%5Boffset%5D=&p%5Blink%5D=all&p%5Bsort%5D=&p%5Bheaders%5D=show&p%5Bmainlabel%5D=&p%5Bintro%5D=&p%5Boutro%5D=&p%5Bsearchlabel%5D=...%20further%20results&p%5Bdefault%5D=&p%5Bclass%5D=sortable%20wikitable%20smwtable&eq=yes)

Comment: I understand in theory how that should work, however in this case I'm not sure it can - because each one of those cells is generated from information spanning 5 subobjects (or 10, when it's breaking) -- the queries to generate the cells are e.g. `|{{#ask:[[Summary Pagename::{{{?Summary Pagename}}}]][[Summary MatchNo::{{{?Summary MatchNo}}}]][[SP GameNo::{{{?Summary GameNo}}}]][[SP PlayerCo::{{lc:{{#var:ourcolor}}}}]]|?SP Champ|?SP PlayerNo|format=list|sort=SP PlayerNo|mainlabel=-|template=Cimh|sep=}}` and to split it up into 5 queries would slow the page creation I think.

Comment: [link to template](http://lol.esportspedia.com/w/index.php?title=Template:MatchHistoryTeam/Line&action=edit)